# How to put AND statement within a IF Vlookup & ISNA formula

Tags: if-statement

I would like to put an AND statement within the below formula but I keep getting the error "You have entered too few arguments", is anyone able to help please?

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$D$4,1,FALSE)),"No","Yes")`

Comment: Show what formula you attempted, since you're asking how to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Replace commas with semicolons and use AND function in IF condition.

Worked for me in google sheets.

```
=IF(AND(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2;$D$2:$D$4;1;FALSE)); TRUE);"No";"Yes")
```

Hope it helps!

[image: Image of error]

Comment: Thanks, but where would you put the AND statement?

Comment: @James How is anyone meant to say, when you didn't explain _what_ `AND` statement you're trying to add, to achieve what goal?

Comment: You must add AND function. I edited my answer. :)
If my answer helped you, please mark it as resolved.

Have a nice day!

Comment: @Jakub thank you for your response, your time is much appreciated but I still cannot get this to work :( here is my formula  
 =IF(AND(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C2;'[Finance & Order Value Queries.xlsx]Proforma Orders'!$C:$C;A2="Pending Prepayment";FALSE)); TRUE);"No";"Yes")

Comment: So Basically, if A2 is "Pending Prepayment" and the formula cannot find the value of C2 within '[Finance & Order Value Queries.xlsx]Proforma Orders'!$C:$C then I would like the formula to say "No"

Comment: And what does it say?

Comment: @Jakub I have added an image into the question of the error that comes up now, again I appreciate your time

Comment: I don't see any image :)